# How to use post method in volley library in android?

Tags: android, android-volley

Explanation: 
           Here, i am tried to insert user data into MySQL database table through my android application using volley library.I almost done everything but my code not working.

Here is my Registration.java activity

```
public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private TextInputLayout inputLayoutName,inputLayoutEmail,inputLayoutPassword;
    private Button btnSignUp,btn_image;
    private EditText inputName,inputEmail,inputPassword;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ImageButton imageButton;
    private CircleImageView circularImageView;
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    private String url="http://My_ip_add/test/v1/register";

    private String KEY_NAME="name";
    private String KEY_EMAIL="email";
    private String KEY_PASSWORD="password";

    private String name="";
    private String email="";
    private String password="";
    private String image="";
    //    Map<String,String> params;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_button));
        }

        circularImageView=(CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.circleView);
        inputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_name);
        inputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_email);
        inputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_password);

        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);

        btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        imageButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        inputName.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputName));
        inputEmail.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputEmail));
        inputPassword.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputPassword));


    }

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
    private boolean validateName() {
        if (inputName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            inputLayoutName.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_name));
            requestFocus(inputName);
            return false;
        } else {
            inputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        return true;
    }
    private boolean validateEmail() {
        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty() || !isValidEmail(email)) {
            inputLayoutEmail.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_email));
            requestFocus(inputEmail);
            return false;
        } else {
            inputLayoutEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        return true;
    }
    private static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }
    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        String encodedImage = encodeToBase64(bmp,Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image,Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat,int quality){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(compressFormat,quality,baos);
        return Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
//                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.circularimage);
                Bitmap circularBitmap = ImageConverter.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, 100);

                circularImageView.setImageBitmap(circularBitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private void requestFocus(View view) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    private boolean validatePassword() {
        if (inputPassword.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            inputLayoutPassword.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_password));
            requestFocus(inputPassword);
            return false;
        } else {
            inputLayoutPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        return true;
    }
    private void submitForm() {
        if (!validateName()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!validateEmail()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!validatePassword()) {
            return;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.btn_signup) {
            submitForm();
            name=inputName.getText().toString().trim();
            email=inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            password=inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            Log.e("res",""+password);
            RegisterUser();
        }

        if(v.getId()==R.id.imageButton){
            showFileChooser();
        }
    }
    private void RegisterUser(){
        JsonObjectRequest JsonObjReq=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Toast.makeText(Registration.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Registration.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                //return super.getParams();

                name=inputName.getText().toString().trim();
                email=inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                password=inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                Log.e("name values",""+name);
                Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();

                params.put(KEY_NAME,name);
                params.put(KEY_EMAIL,email);
                params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
                return params;
            }
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return headers;
            }
        };
        //Creating a Request Queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(JsonObjReq);
    }
    private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private View view;

        private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.input_name:
                    validateName();
                    break;
                case R.id.input_email:
                    validateEmail();
                    break;
                case R.id.input_password:
                    validatePassword();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

In above class i have registeruser() method which execute after click on sign up button.

I search everywhere in statckoverflow but didn't got valid solution.

If i used a legacy http then it's working correctly.

Here is my http legacy code

```
private class Register extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    ServiceHandler sh=new ServiceHandler();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        List<NameValuePair> param=new ArrayList<>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
        String jsonstr=sh.makeServiceCall(url,ServiceHandler.POST,param);
        return jsonstr;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Log.e("RESPONSE",""+s);
    }
}
```

Above class working very well.Not working using volley library.

if i insert the data using REST api client add-one then my data inserted successfully into the database.

Here is my log

```
05-04 15:02:06.585 32275-32275/com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays E/name values: keyurkeyur.hirani@gmail.comkeyur
05-04 15:02:06.684 32275-4459/com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays E/Volley: [200] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://ip_Addr/test/v1/register
05-04 15:02:10.197 32275-32345/com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa2c97bd0
```

Please help me to solve out this problem

Comment: Try commenting out the getHeaders() method in volley or try changing the content-type.

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: @MilanGajera based on you log output, the url that you are using is not valid: my_ip_add/test/v1/register 

Have you tried changing the url variable before running the code above?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the content type on the header, try to change it on the body contents.

Replace this:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    return headers;
}
```

with this:

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "application/json";
}
```

---

You could also try setting the content type to: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is the default content type.

Comment: @MilanGajera does it give you the same error? Can you copy the log output here?

Comment: @MilanGajera Please try setting the content type to default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (or [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) if you are on a Mac) and see what goes wrong with the request as your logging doesn't give much input back.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code and see if it work. I removed the getParams() method and setting the parameters in the new JSONObject(params) when making the request.

```
private void RegisterUser(){
 name=inputName.getText().toString().trim();
 email=inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
 password=inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

 Log.e("name values",""+name);
 Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();

 params.put(KEY_NAME,name);
 params.put(KEY_EMAIL,email);
 params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);

    JsonObjectRequest JsonObjReq=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }){

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    //Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(JsonObjReq);
}
```

Comment: Still i got error BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for

Comment: Please post your log output.

Comment: i created a new project and implement new task i got same error

Comment: I used a xammp server as my local server.

Answer (score 0):

For calling post method in Volley follow below steps.

Put this Method in Your Application Class

```
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

 public static synchronized BatooniApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }
```

This code write where you want to call web service

```
/**
     * Making json object request
      */
    private void makeRegistrationRequest() {

        String url = "your url"
        JSONObject requestJson = getJsonRequest();
// here we  pass into Response.Listener JSONObject if you are getting jsonarray or string change it accordingly  
               final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, requestJson,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                       // parse your response here

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

            }
        }) {
            /**
             * Passing some request headers
             * */
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // TODO future task
                return params;
            }
        };
        // Adding request to request queue
        Application.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,
                AppConstant.METHOD_REGISTRATION);

      }
```

Method for prepare json object  for passing into post method

```
/**
     * make json request
     *
     * @return
     */
    private JSONObject getJsonRequest() {
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        try {

            params.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, "Rohitashv");
            params.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, "Jain");
            params.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER, "12121212");
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL_ADDRESS, "abc@gmail.com");

            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return params;
    }
```

Make sure pass object of Response Listener according to your web service response other wise you not get call back into the method.

Comment: please see bottom of makeRegistrationRequest method i am adding request queue their.
and also describe need to add static method into your application class

Comment: what is AppConstant??

Comment: replace AppConstant.METHOD_REGISTRATION  with your String TAG like

"Registration"

Comment: not still there i this i am used slim framework to create a rest api i tired another tutorial available on http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: have you tried ever your web service is working properly or not,
if not please test on google postman or ant other tool